# What is exact url to connect to an RPC SOAP Service

Tags: java, axis

I have MyService (AXIS 1.4 service) available through this url:

```
curl http://localhost:9999/prefix/services/MyService?wsdl
```

putting it to the browser query line I have XML WSDL back.

The question is: which URL should I use in the code to connect to MyService to invoke particular methode there?

This is my code to connect I have for now:

```
InterfacePortType_Stub stub 
                              = (InterfacePortType_Stub) myService.getPort();

stub._setProperty(javax.xml.rpc.Stub.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, 
    "http://localhost:9999/prefix/services/MyService");

this.port = stub;

final MyResponse myResponse = port.myMethod(myRequest);
```

So, I use `**http://localhost:9999/prefix/services/MyService**` string to connect. But it does not work - myResponse.status = fail.

In the top of my generated files I have a header like this:

> ```
> // This class was generated by the JAXRPC SI, do not edit.
> // Contents subject to change without notice.
> // JAX-RPC Standard Implementation (1.1.2_01, build R40)
> // Generated source version: 1.1.2
> ```

Comment: it seems this article: http://finallyigotit.blogspot.ca/2009/05/jax-rpc-vs-jax-ws.html is about my case

Comment: ok I found the solution. it juts was stupid mistake. all above is correct. url is ok there.

Answer (score 1):

To call Axis service it first needs to be correctly initialized. Your code should look something like this:

```
//Your service interface.
InterfacePortTypeService proxy = null;

//Create a locator instance from Axis generated class.
InterfacePortTypeLocator locator = new InterfacePortTypeLocator();

//Get your service from locator.
proxy = locator.getInterfacePortType(new URL("http://localhost:9999/prefix/services/MyService"));

//Call your methods;
proxy.someMethod();
```

I don't know the names of all your generated classes, so this is just an example how to initialize `Axis` service.

Comment: I guess your InterfacePortTypeService is my InterfacePortType_Stub - this is a representer of the MyServer on server side. But I dod not find any Locator(s). I found: InterfacePortType_My_RequestStruct, InterfacePortType_My_RequestStruct_SOAPBuilder, InterfacePortType_My_RequestStruct_SOAPSerializer, InterfacePortType_My_ResponseStruct, InterfacePortType_My_ResponseStruct_SOAPBuilder, InterfacePortType_My_ResponseStruct_SOAPSerializer, InterfacePortType_Stub

Comment: The locator, should contain the method to get your actual generated interface. This method should take java.net.URL as a parameter to which you have to pass your endpoint, without ?wsdl extension. These classes seems to be like JAX-RPC generated, not Axis. You mentioned in your question that your are using Axis 1.4.

Comment: Take a look here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JAXRPC4.html how to create JAX-RPC client.

Comment: it was generated by the JAXRPC SI (I've put notice about it in my post)